# How to use C Language to print the image below?

Tags: c, plot

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxuIY.jpg).

How to use the function of `fprint` to  draw the image?
The equation is `x(t)= -2 * t * sin( t * t )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in plotting functions in C.

You have to check the plotting and graph libraries and see if they fit your needs:

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/Main.html)
a library for making high-quality scientific graphics under Linux and Window.

[PLplot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/)
PLplot works on the following platforms:

Linux, Mac OS X, and other Unices
MSVC IDE on the Microsoft version of Windows (Windows 2000 and later)
Cygwin on the Microsoft version of Windows
MinGW-w64/MSYS2 on the Microsoft version of Windows

[Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) a command-line driven plotting engine that runs on all 
major operating systems (Windows, GNU/Linux, OSX, etc.).\
Gnuplot provides a large array of styles to produce different plots including plots popular in mathematics, statistics, or even financial analysis.  It can also produce various plot styles for three dimensional data including surface and contour plots. 
It is capable of plotting user defined functions or specific data and can even generate
 data through various facilities if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in *standard* C11 (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) because it does not know about graphics. In practice, *your question is operating system specific*.

Practically speaking, you could use some GUI or graphics library (or [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit)) like [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) (and many others).

Another approach is to communicate (using some kind of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) with some existing program able to draw such graphics. You might (at least on Linux) use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).